# "Leave for better" or "Leave for the better"?

Tags: grammar, word-choice

I would like to say something like "Go out and play great outdoors" using different words.

Thus, I would like to use these words: "leave, enjoy outdoors, better life".

Here I made it, but does it make any sense?

> *Leave for better!*
>   or
>   *Leave for the better!*

Another suggestion was "Leave it better" which means "stay as it is better, or protect".

What can I say?

Comment: Neither _Leave for better_ or the variants make any sense, and certainly do not mean the same as _Go and play outdoors_. You need to explain more of the context - is it a slogan of some kind?

Comment: To me "Leave for better" makes no sense while "Leave for the better" sounds like a recommendation that the person emigrates. It sounds a bit like the old American exhortation: "Go West, young man" or the old Australian emigration advertisments in Britain at the time of the £10 Poms: "Australia, it's a great place for kids".

Answer (score 1):

"Leave for better!" does not make any sense by itself in this context. It sounds like you are trying to say something like "make life a better place"?

"Go outside, enjoy life, and make it a better place!" makes more sense to me.